# NodeJs: Load different CSS depending on routes parameters

Tags: node.js, pug

I've looked around a bit, but I'm not even sure that what I want is possible.

app.js

```
...
var routes = require('./routes/index');
...
app.use('/', routes);
...
```

index.js

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { 
        title: 'Test',
        headersheet: 'header',
        mainsheet: 'devTest',
        navbar: 'nav_bar',
        mainscript: 'devTest',
    });
});
```

Then, my layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/global.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/#{headersheet}.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/#{mainsheet}.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/#{navbar}.css')
    body
        block content
        script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js')
        script(src='javascripts/#{mainscript}.js')
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block content   
    include nav_bar.jade

    #page_header_fr
```

Basically what I want is that the `#{mainsheet}.css` becomes `devTest.css`

But what I see in my consoles when the pages load is a message telling me that the resource `undefined.css` could not be find. Now, what I understand from that is that the parameters (headersheet, mainsheet, navbar, ...) are not properly being transmitted. However, the title of the page displays just fine.

Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (adding "" to your mainsheet, navbar and mainscript):
index.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { 
        title: 'Test',
        headersheet: 'header',
        "mainsheet": 'devTest',
        "navbar": 'nav_bar',
        "mainscript": 'devTest',
    });
});
```

That should work.